# FLT Can't Validate XSD Boolean

Tags: xml, xsd, boolean, freemarker

I'm working on a web project for my job and I'm attempting to add a Google survey to pages, by way of clicking a check box on the template side. The reason for this method is to add the script to all templates, but have the ability to turn it off/on on specific pages. If checked, show survey. If not, don't show survey.

My XSD schema boolean code is:

```
<xs:element name="ShowSurvey" type="xs:boolean"/>
```

This is the check box to be rendered on the publisher's template end.

My FTL code is:

```
<#if !Page.ShowSurvey> 
<script type="text/javascript" async="" defer=""  src="//survey.g.doubleclick.net/async_survey?site=#############"></script>
</#if>
```

When I go to regenerate the template, I get the following error message:

> error regenerating rendition using TemplateName.ftl: freemarker.core.NonBooleanException: Error on line 13, column 23 in freemarker_template Expecting a boolean (true/false) expression here Expression Page.ShowSurvey does not evaluate to true/false it is an instance of freemarker.ext.dom.NodeListModel

What am I doing wrong? Could anyone shine some light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker's XML wrapper is not XSD-aware, so you have a string like `"true"` there, not a boolean. So you will have to convert it to boolean yourself. Something like `<#if !xsdBool(Page.ShowSurvey)>` where `xsdBool` is:

```
<#function xsdBool s>
    <#if s == 'true' || s == '1'><#return true></#if>
    <#if s == 'false' || s == '0'><#return false></#if>
    <#stop "Malformed XSD boolean: " + s>
</#function>
```